# Printing the sum of two functions function f1 and f2

Tags: class, methods, addition, fractions

The question tells me to... write a main method that constructs 2 fractions 5/7 and 3/8 and then create 2 other fractions whose values are the sum and product of the original fractions

```
public class Fraction
{
    int num;

    int den;

    public int sum;

    public int getAddition()
    {
        sum = (this.num + other.num);
        return sum;
    }
}


public class tester
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
       Fraction f1 = new Fraction ();

       f1.num = 5;

       f1.den = 7;

       Fraction f2 = new Fraction ();

       f2.num = 3;

       f2.den = 8;

       //Fraction f3 = getAddition();

       Fraction f4 = new Fraction ();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain what your question is outside of the code?

Comment: So what's the actual question?

Comment: Your entire post does not have to compile. You do not need to put your question as an inline comment. Also, could you add the `C#` tag?

Answer (score 0):

`other` needs to be a parameter of the addition function, and get called by one of the `Fraction` objects. If you want a function that takes both of them as parameters, use a class (static) method. In any case, you cannot assign an `int` to a class. You either assign the resulting fields to the calling object  or you create a new Fraction with the new values and return that object.

Most importantly, that's not how you add fractions. That how you add them if the base is the same.